# one instance per junit instead of each new instance per test case

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have current existing junit case like this below.

What i need is to just have one instance and start the server once instead of Junit call the constructor every test case . Can i achieve this without using static ?

```
public class TestIntegration{
    public Server testServer;

    public TestIntegration(){
        testServer = new TestServer();
        testServer.start();
    }         

    @Test
    public void test1(){
            System.out.println("Test 1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
            System.out.println("Test 2");
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Singleton pattern:

```
public class TestIntegration{
public final static Server testServer = new Server();

private TestIntegration() {
    }     
}
```

Then call

```
TestIntegration.testServer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, one instance of testing class per test is the way JUnit works.

But you can achieve what you are trying to do using @BeforeClass annotation and static.

```
public class TestIntegration{

  public static TestIntegration testServer;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void  TestIntegration(){
    testServer = new TestIntegration();
    testServer.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void test1(){
    System.out.println("Test 1");
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(){
    System.out.println("Test 2");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with non-static objects, use the Annotation @Before:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    testServer = new TestServer();
    testServer.start();
}
```

This will start your server before running the tests.

Check out further information: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

Seems we can use test instance per class in junit 5. These is what we are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the code below to the top of the class to have one instance per class.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```